# Word for the climax of a magic show

Tags: word-request

- The word's meaning is close to the climax of a magic show. Close, but please don't quote me on that.
- It begins with letter "p", and contains a letter "t". Again, off the top of my head again.
- It was the title of a Hollywood movie around year 2006, +/- 3 years.

What is that word?

Comment: Probably a question for english.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the film, [The Prestige](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Prestige_(film))

> **Every great magic trick consists of three parts or acts**. The first part is called "The Pledge". The magician shows you something ordinary: a deck of cards, a bird or a man. He shows you this object. Perhaps he asks you to inspect it to see if it is indeed real, unaltered, normal. But of course...it probably isn't. The second act is called "The Turn". **The magician takes the ordinary something and makes it do something extraordinary**. Now you're looking for the secret... but you won't find it, because of course you're not really looking. You don't really want to know. You want to be fooled. But you wouldn't clap yet. Because making something disappear isn't enough; you have to bring it back. **That's why every magic trick has a third act, the hardest part, the part we call "The Prestige"**.

Whether or not this is true magician lingo, I wouldn't know.

Comment: OMG, That's it! Exactly what I was looking for! You are amazing, giving just such limited clues.Thanks!